# Printing with NSTextfield crash

Tags: objective-c, printing, nstextfield

I have an app (Xcode4.5, 10.8) that works with airfoil coordinates.
The airfoils show up on screen and can be printed.
Now I want to add a title on the printed airfoil in the print method.
I have an NSView Druckfeld to which I add the subview with the airfoil drawing.
then I add the title with

```
NSTextField* Titelfeld = [[NSTextField alloc]initWithFrame:Titelrect];
NSFont* TitelFont=[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 14];
[Titelfeld setFont:TitelFont];  
[Titelfeld setStringValue:@"Profil"];
[Druckfeld addSubview:Titelfeld];
[Titelfeld release];
```

The title is shown in the print dialog, but hitting the OK butten lets the app jump to 
return NSApplicationMain, showing the alert 'Processing page: 1'. Nothing is shown in the log window.
In the console, I read
07.Oktober.12 10:47:25.074 com.apple.debugserver-194[85172]: 1 +0.000000 sec [14cb4/0303]: error: ::ptrace (request = PT_THUPDATE, pid = 0x14cb5, tid = 0x1c07, signal = 0) err = Resource busy (0x00000010)

cups access_log writes:
localhost - - [07/Oct/2012:10:36:09 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 126367 CUPS-Get-Document successful-ok
localhost - - [07/Oct/2012:10:36:32 +0200] "POST /printers/Laser_home HTTP/1.1" 200 1713 Create-Job successful-ok

cups error_log writes:
E [07/Oct/2012:10:37:13 +0200] [Job 377] Aborting job because it has no files.

But:
- Adding the title on the screen with the same code works fine.
- Doing the same in Druckfeld with

```
   NSImageView* Bildfeld;
NSRect Bildrect = NSMakeRect(230, 80, 60, 60);
Bildfeld = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:Bildrect];
[Bildfeld setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"home"]];
[Druckfeld addSubview:Bildfeld];
[Bildfeld release];
```

prints fine.

Any ideas what is going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your german right? ;)
Sorry, I don't really understan your problem, but two things: start with a small Character for variables: titleFeld instead of Titlefeld. Capital letters at beginning are mostly objects, your code has to have a good view, otherwise you don't know what you did when you watch your code later ;)
2. you should use english names titleField... :)

But this is your choice i just suggest

Comment: Apple's naming conventions are here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html